# How do I build ISO Week Number table programatically in T-SQL query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Anyone knows how to built temp table of week using T-SQL query?

I heard there has a lot of type of calculations for that, Gregorian or etc... My needs are ISO Week No and bind to temp table depends on week no.

The temp table has 2 columns : `ISOWeekNo` and `WeekName`

```
ISOWeekNo   WeekName
1           01 Jan 2013 To 07 Jan 2013
2           08 Jan 2013 To 14 Jan 2013
```

How do I build programmatically in T-SQL Query based on ISO Week No?

Updated : I want to pass the parameter year only. e.g : 2013

Comment: The ISO week you describe doesn't seem to conform to the standard? The first ISO week of this year should be 31 Dec 2012 To 6 Jan 2013 if I understand http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date correctly

Comment: yes you are right, the below code will work if I know ISOweek start & end date.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Then my code submission should work for you. But, I am not certain that I have provided the optimum solution in terms of performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Added WHERE clause to terminate for sought year only.

This seems to match the Wikipedia description and I am sure there is room for optimisation.
Mikael, I copied your formatting code for the friendly column, thank you.
This code will work on SQL Server 2008 onwards because of the use of the ISOWEEK datepart.

```
use tempdb
go

DECLARE  @Year          SMALLINT = 2013
        ,@FirstISOWKDay DATETIME

;WITH FindISOWEEKFirstDay AS
(
    SELECT DT   = DATEADD(DAY, -7, DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, 1, 1))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, DT)
    FROM FindISOWEEKFirstDay
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, DT) < DATEADD(DAY, 14, DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, 1, 1))
)
SELECT TOP 1 @FirstISOWKDay = DT
FROM FindISOWEEKFirstDay
WHERE DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DT) = 1
ORDER BY DT ASC -- Eliminate probability of arb sorting (Thanks Mikael)
;WITH Base10 (n) AS
(
    SELECT 1    UNION ALL   SELECT 1    UNION ALL   SELECT 1    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1    UNION ALL   SELECT 1    UNION ALL   SELECT 1    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1    UNION ALL   SELECT 1    UNION ALL   SELECT 1    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1    
)
,Base1000 (n) AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1
    FROM Base10 T1, Base10 T2, Base10 T3
)
SELECT   Start      = DATEADD(DAY, n*7, @FirstISOWKDay)
        ,[End]      = DATEADD(DAY, n*7 + 6, @FirstISOWKDay)
        ,Friendly   = CONVERT(VARCHAR(101), DATEADD(DAY, n*7, @FirstISOWKDay), 106)+' To '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(101), DATEADD(DAY, n*7 + 6, @FirstISOWKDay), 106)
        ,ISOWEEK    = DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, n*7, @FirstISOWKDay))
FROM Base1000
-- Filter to terminate, resulting only in sought year's calendar
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, n*7 + 6, @FirstISOWKDay)) = @Year
```

Comment: a few years I tested. It's work very well. Only one things, some years it shows more than one year. for e.g: 2013, the results will come out 2014 also. But that's not big deal. Thanks for your solution. You make my day. :)
and @Mikael thanks also your help. :)

Comment: There will be overlaps of years because of the definition of an ISO WEEK. One attribute of an ISO week is the first week with the year's first Thursday in it.

Comment: As another footnote, the BaseN CTEs can be modified for better performance so that only the number of rows required by are returned. For example, if one only required 50 rows, you could Base10, Base5 resulting in a Cartesian product of 50.

Comment: Your query against `FindISOWEEKFirstDay` does a `TOP 1` without and order by. That will leave SQL Server free to return any row it chooses. To be sure you will have the first day of week 1 you should add `ORDER BY DT` or you could do `SELECT @FirstISOWKDay = MIN(DT)`.

Comment: Mikael, very good point in the case of heaps. In my testing it seemed safe to rely on the CTE's ordering.
But, I agree with your prudence, there should be an ORDER BY. Thank you for your contribution, I will modify my code. The modification does cause additional overhead to the code segment~100% Better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @Year int;
set @Year = 2016;

with C as
(
  select datefromparts(@Year, 1, 1) as D
  union all
  select dateadd(day, 1, C.D)
  from C
  where C.D < datefromparts(@Year, 12, 31)
)
select datepart(iso_week, C.D) as ISOWeekNo,
       convert(varchar(101), min(C.D), 106)+' To '+convert(varchar(101), max(C.D), 106) as WeekName
from C
group by datepart(iso_week, C.D),
         case when datepart(month, C.D) = 12 and
                   datepart(iso_week, C.D) > 50
           then 1
           else 0 
         end
order by min(C.D)
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Result:

```
ISOWeekNo   WeekName
----------- --------------------------
53          01 Jan 2016 To 03 Jan 2016
1           04 Jan 2016 To 10 Jan 2016
2           11 Jan 2016 To 17 Jan 2016
3           18 Jan 2016 To 24 Jan 2016
4           25 Jan 2016 To 31 Jan 2016
5           01 Feb 2016 To 07 Feb 2016
6           08 Feb 2016 To 14 Feb 2016
7           15 Feb 2016 To 21 Feb 2016
.
.
.
47          21 Nov 2016 To 27 Nov 2016
48          28 Nov 2016 To 04 Dec 2016
49          05 Dec 2016 To 11 Dec 2016
50          12 Dec 2016 To 18 Dec 2016
51          19 Dec 2016 To 25 Dec 2016
52          26 Dec 2016 To 31 Dec 2016
```

Comment: wow! thanks! I want to use only one parameter. for e.g : I pass the parameter 2013, the result will come out. Sorry for my mistake. In my questions, I forgot to metion about that.

Comment: @CMMaung: Is it so difficult to calculate the start and ending date yourself?

Comment: @alzaimar above that code, I put some query like that

`Declare @year datetime
Declare @start datetime
Declare @end datetime

Set @year = '2012'

SET @start = (convert(char(20), convert(char(4), year(@year)) + '-Jan-01', 111))

SET @end = (convert(char(20), convert(char(4), year(@year) + 1) + '-Dec-31', 111))`

but got error

Comment: @alzaimar btw, if I know, no need to ask either way if you know, I'll appreciate your answer. Thanks

Comment: @CMMaung I have changed the query to show the dates for a given year. There are some years that starts with week 52 or week 53 and that made things a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
Select date '2012-12-31' + level*7                WK_STARTS_DT
 , to_char(date '2012-12-31' + level*7, 'IW') ISO_WEEK
 , to_char(date '2012-12-31' + level*7, 'WW') WEEK
From dual
Connect By Level <= 
(
 Select Round( (ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'Y'),12)-TRUNC(SYSDATE,'Y') )/7, 0) From dual
) --365/7 
/

WK_STARTS_DT    ISO_WEEK    WEEK
------------------------------------
1/7/2013             02    01
1/14/2013            03    02
1/21/2013            04    03
......
2/4/2013             06    05
2/11/2013            07    06
......
3/4/2013             10    09
```

To confirm week numbers:
http://www.epochconverter.com/date-and-time/weeknumbers-by-year.php?year=2013